# Store fetched query into global array PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I'm trying to create a global variable which contains user specific data from my database. I've been looking over the internet but I couldn't find the right answer. I'm not quite sure how to approach this.

At this point of code, the user has been registered and logged in and his login data is saved inside $s_email and $s_password, which are session variables.

Here's some code (mysql.php) which contains the mysql class:

```
class mysql {

// Create database connection
private $db;
function __construct() {
    $this->db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) or 
                die('Database fout.');
}

// Receive user data based on cookie, then fetch this data into an array
function getUserData($s_email, $s_password, $data){

    $sql = "SELECT 
                `id`, 
                `firstname`, 
                `lastname`, 
                `city`,
                `country`,
                `gender`,
                `bio`,
                `active`,
                `member_since`
            FROM `users` 
            WHERE email = '$s_email' 
            AND password ='$s_password'"; 

    // perform the query and store the result
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);

    // if the $result contains at least one row
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

      // output data of each row from $result
        $data = array();
        global $data;

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $data[] = $row;
        } 
    }
}
```

}

And this is my profile.php which will try to run the function (the echo $data[''] does not work, but that's the kind of approach I would like to take on this system):

```
    <?php
        // Receive user data and send it to mysql class
        $mysql->getUserData($s_email, $s_password, $data);
        echo $data['email'];
    ?>
```

Eventually I'm trying to create a simple access method to the array variables.

NOTE: I've only been scripting PHP and MySQL for 2 days, so any advice on my code is really appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: you can save these values in session if you want to access data on all pages.

Comment: You should probably avoid global variables unless they're necessary. If you can get away with returning $data in your getUserData method, then I would suggest you just do it that way. You can then just do $data=mysql->getUserData($s_email, $s_password, $data);

Comment: @BlahArgh thank you for the comment. And how could I select one specific item from this array then?

Comment: please, stop using global variables

Comment: Well, from the code you posted, if only one data set is found, then you can access the elements by using $data[0]['id'], $data[0]['firstname'], etc. If you're sure that the method is only suppose to find one dataset, then you can just return $result->fetch_assoc(), then you can skip the "[0]" part and just access the elements using $data['id'], $data['firstname'], etc.

Comment: BTW, you're trying to access $data['email'], but you never requested that column in your SQL statement. You'll need to add "email" to your SELECT clause if you want to get it.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. In this short example you have a number of dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) coming from a reckless lack of [proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) built-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use globals.

In your function (don't use `$data` as an argument):

```
function getUserData($s_email, $s_password) {
    // code

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Then to use it (don't pass `$data` as an argument):

```
$data = $mysql->getUserData($s_email, $s_password);
```

Now you have rows so loop over them:

```
foreach($data as $row) {
    echo $row['email'];
}
```

And you need to select `email` in the query.

Comment: Hello, this seems to work mostly, however the selection $data['email'] doesn't work. I suspect it needs to be something like $data[2]['email'], any suggestions how to approve this?

Answer (score 0):

I will first tell you how to do it and right after will explain why you shouldnt be doing that.

**How to do it**

To let the getUserData method to alter the value of the $data variable you are giving as argument you need to pass it by reference, like this:

`function getUserData($s_email, $s_password, &$data)` {

**Why you should not be doing this in this situation**

Keeping things brief. Because there are by far better approaches (like the one [AbraCadaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2844319/abracadaver) is suggesting) and you dont really need to pass the $data by reference in the first place.